# Tuple (unmodifiable ordered list of heterogeneous elements) support in Java

Tags: java, tuples

I wonder why Java doesn't have a tuple data structure implementation in its standard library. For instance C++ has [a very good implementation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) of this fixed-size collection of heterogeneous values. The same in [Haskell](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Tuple.html). In Java I only know [javatuples](http://www.javatuples.org/) and some support in [Functional Java](https://github.com/functionaljava/functionaljava) library via `Product` (`P1 - P8`) types. I wonder why `tuple` or at least `pair` not in standard library at all? Even Android SDK developers added their [own implementation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Pair.html) of 2-tuple (pair).

Comment: name a good use case for general-purpose tuples? generally speaking these sorts of structures are bad for type safety and most of the time can be substituted with collections. i know drools use tuples, but not from a library

Comment: @radai There a lot of them. The most evident - instead of writing a class for every time you want to put 2 or more different things together, there's a ready for use solution that does it for you.Yes, tuple not safe. But all is not safe in imperative languages!Why then we don't use languages like Haskell in commercial and enterprise development? Because we want easy solutions.

Comment: Guava has made an explicit decision _not_ to provide tuple types.  Some explanation can be found [here](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/IdeaGraveyard).

Comment: i think the guava explanation hits the nail on the head. any time you want to put 2+ things together youre better off naming the resulting combination :-)

Comment: "Because other languages have them" is a _bad_ reason to add a thing to a language.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The "Java way" is to define use-specific classes rather than these sorts of lightweight semi-class types. If you think about it, a tuple is really just a simplified struct; the Java folks would prefer you to just go ahead and create the struct.

This perspective is changing a bit, especially in Java 8 with its lambdas (which put pressure on the JDK to provide generic `Function`-type interfaces rather than use-case-specific interfaces like `FooCallback`). But it's still a fairly strong mindset for a lot of Java developers, and there's some sense to it. Java is a very statically typed language; a tuple is somewhere between static typing and dynamic typing, in that there's nothing in the type system to prevent you from thinking this `(int, String)` that represents a customer ID and name is actually an `(int, String)` representing an order ID and its description.

See, for instance, [this discussion](https://web.archive.org/web/20121223214101/http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/IdeaGraveyard) ("Tuples for n >= 2") on the issue within the Guava project. Granted, that's not official; but it's a good representation of the Java mindset.

Comment: Then why don't you create a class for every tuple of arity 1? There's nothing in the type system to prevent you from thinking this `int` that represents a customer ID is actually an `int` representing an order ID.

Comment: @SargeBorsch In short, because Java isn't well designed for that pattern. Classes have overhead in performance, complexity (is it null?) and reflection (not a drop-in replacemtnt for an int). If you have to pay that cost anyway, you may as well do it right; if you don't, it's more of a balancing act. But to your point, I actually wish that Java did have something like Haskell's `newtype`, which would let you create a CustomerId which is a type-safe int.

Comment: Yup, Java draws a line in the sand between primitives and classes. No avoiding it.

Comment: But all is not lost, there is some interesting workarounds in Scala. (unified type system, specialization, ...)

Comment: @SargeBorsch I do just that wherever I can. Using id's instead of objects isn't the common path in most of my projects anyway.

Comment: I wish the "this dicussion" link still worked, I'm curious. I have the same intuition. Tuples like Pair feel like a concept that wandered out of Python and strayed into Java in a drunken stupor. There should be a better semantic binding between the elements so you know *why* they belong together and what their relationship is. Bob and Teri are a married couple, not just a Pair of people with an unknown relationship because their Author was too lazy to define marriage. Otherwise they could just be next-door neighbors, you wouldn't know.

Comment: @BobDoolittle I found the page on the wayback machine and updated the link. Thanks for the nudge! That said, there isn't anything on that page that you didn't already know. :-) I originally posted this question a while ago, but I think I was mostly trying to cite a well-adopted project to say that this isn't just my opinion, it's shared by others.

Answer (score 9):

There is a nice library called `javatuples`. It defines generic tuple types for arities from 1(`Unit`) to 10(`Decade`) and all essential methods like `equals`, `hashCode`, `toString` and even `compareTo`.

Official site: http://www.javatuples.org/
Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.javatuples</groupId>
    <artifactId>javatuples</artifactId>
    <version>[version]</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

(at the moment latest version is `1.2`)

Comment: BTW, it's very easy to spot it by searching in google "java tuples".

Answer (score 4):

It has:

```
Collections.unmodifiableList(yourList)
```

will do the trick.

I think that the versatility of the JCF makes the existence of explicit tuple datastructures unnecessary.

<sub>I assume that by *tuple* you mean an ordered immutable list of elements (according to the [wikipedia definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple)).</sub>

As for the 3rd party library my power search on google yielded [this](http://www.javatuples.org/), [this](http://code.google.com/p/fasttuple/) and of course [this](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.java?r=80).

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @PaulBellora tuple = unmodifiable list

Comment: By tuple I mean just a product algebraic data type. And as far as I know in imperative languages tuples sometimes implemented as mutable data structures

Comment: FYI, Guava's `ImmutableList` is considered safer than `unmodifiableList` as `unmodifiableList` can still result in a `ConcurrentModificationException`

Comment: @JoséRobertoAraújoJúnior Understood - I read the OP's use of "heterogeneous" to mean something like `Tuple2<String, Integer>` etc.

Comment: I know about `ImmutableList` but it is not part of the JCF I was talking about. Thanks for pointing it out though.

Comment: In statically&strongly typed languages, tuple is more than just a fixed size list, because its type does contain information about the types of its elements. So N-element tuple has N type parameters. Lists have only one type parameter, that means, each list element has the same (compile-time) type.

Comment: There are a number of concepts which can be implemented in java but in a handicapped version. A good example might be a Trait or a Mixin. Therefore java developers are usually only implementing what is necessary. As you can see in my answer I assumed something which is based on the wikipedia definition.

Answer (score 2):

There is a type in the Java runtime and it is called Entry. This is an interface inside Map and there are simple implementation of it inside AbstractMap.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleEntry.html

You can use it as a tuple for two members, you can even apply generics. I would think hard what I did wrong if ever I needed more elements than two. Probably worth it own class then.

Answer (score 1):

A colleague and I were discussing this a few weeks ago. The only solution I could come up with was to internally store the values in a `Map<Class, Object>` and have some accessor method `getValue(Class)`. Otherwise, how do you access the values in your tuple? You can't have a generic `Tuple` class with methods for each member, e.g. `getInteger`, `getString`, etc because those methods would not be known until runtime, when you create the tuple. This also means you could never have two members with the same type -- how would you be able to write such a class so that at runtime, it knew which object to retrieve?

Comment: How would Generics not solve this? `Tuple<String, JComponent> tup = new Tuple<>(); ... panel.add(tup.getLast()); label.setText(tup.getFirst());` This is obviously a forced size of 2 tuple but it's easy enough to have an Object array underneath and have the programmer be responsible for casting. In all my years I've never found a situation where I've needed a tuple data structure where an easy alternative wasn't available.

Comment: So when you want more than 2 elements, what do you do? You can't write `getSecond`, `getThird`, etc. You might as well just have `Object[]` at that point.

Comment: Tuple structures of more than 2 more 3 elements would be a glorified `Object []`, where instead of `getFirst()` `getSecond()` you would have `get(index)`, which is hardly any different to an `Object []` or `List<Object>`. Quite often it might be nice to pair two types together, which for the most part becomes a `Map`.

Answer (score 1):

FunctionalJava has provided a set of `P` (Product) classes that I believe meet this idea. It provides `P1` - `P8` to allow for up to 8 element Tuples. I agree with Guava's explantation of why they are discouraged but there you go.

[FunctionalJava-P](http://functionaljava.googlecode.com/svn/artifacts/3.0/javadoc/fj/P.html)